# How can I show default message if no data and selected value if data available in dropdownlist in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am binding the dropdownlist with some data and display the selected data in dropdownlist also. That works fine with the following code.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.UniformCommentSelected,
                                   new SelectList(item.UniformComment),
                                   item.UniformCommentSelected)
```

Now I want to add default message "Select" for dropdownlist.
I also want to show the selected value in dropdownlist if any and "Select" if not.

If I put "Select" as third parameter in DropDownListFor then it display "Select" for all users. If I put "Select" as 4th parameter in dropdownlist then nothing happens.

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the following code.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.UniformCommentSelected, new SelectList(item.UniformComment),item.UniformCommentSelected == null ? "---Select---" : item.UniformCommentSelected)
```

Comment: More simplified way:  @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.UniformCommentSelected, new SelectList(item.UniformComment),item.UniformCommentSelected ?? "---Select---")

Answer (score 0):

in my project i fill my dropdown list like this it's below

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, new SelectList(Model.Countries, "ID", "Name"), "select", new { @ID = "ddlCountry", @class = "text", Style = "width: 150px;", onchange = "javascript:cascadingdropdown();" })
```

i think this will help you

Comment: (modelItem => item.UniformCommentSelected, new SelectList(item.UniformComment),"Select", item.UniformCommentSelected) If I use this all the drop down have "Select" as selected. How ever I want if any data exist for user then that would be slected else "Select" I get the data form the model using complex Linq.

Comment: you fill this dropdownlist in edit view ? . actually when you use create view then your dropdown list default have a selected index 0 plz tell me your use this in edit view ?

Comment: No I use the List view. I get the data from entity using join in model class.

Answer (score 0):

I usually bind to a collection of SelectListItem's, and manually add the blank of "Please select one..." option to that collection. In the controller (or in the view right before rendering the droplist), I set .Selected = true for the selected option.